# Starting a second business as a Sole Proprietorship, S-Corp, or LLC with a DBA?

Tags: united-states, small-business, limited-liability-company, s-corporation, sole-proprietorship

I'm planning on launching a business to provide voiceover professional services. In professional voiceover, your name is your calling card, so my first inclination would be to simply do everything as a Sole Proprietorship.  Of course, that doesn't protect me from liability, so an S-Corp or LLC seems like a better idea.

However, I'm also thinking about adopting an alias as well.  Thus, my personal name would be one name a locally / regionally-focused name for better marketing would be another.

Assuming I adopt an S-Corp structure, would it be better to use my planned regional / local business name as the primary name?  Or my own name?

Am I making unnecessary work for myself to do that?

Comment: This is really more of a business direction question than personal finance. Just a comment on liability - neither LLC nor SCorp will shield you from liability for your *personal* negligence.

Comment: I figured I was maybe in the wrong spot.  I'm not concerned about personal negligence, here.  The purpose of the LLC / S-Corp is to protect my personal assets in the case the corporation gets sued.  Anyone can pretty much sue at any time for any reason in the US, anyway.

Comment: You'll want to talk to a lawyer about the effectiveness of the liability protection for your use case. Generally, corporate protection doesn't extend to your own wrongdoing, so if the corporation is basically you in disguise then the shield will not be effective (that is compared to liability from employee's actions, third party, or through property ownership).

Comment: What kind of liability are you even concerned with for VO work? Hard to even imagine what kind of risks would apply.